# Get and Store text from looped checkboxes into a String

Tags: android, checkbox, storing-data

I am kinda new in android and java programming, and I have a question, wish you could help me to solve it :)

I have a Program, it will fetch and loop data from database and convert it into some checkboxes, then user must check the checkboxes and hit the submit button,,
The value(s) of the checked checkboxes will be stored to a String[], then will be send to another activity via Intent.putExtra..

So far, all I can do is fetch and loop the data from database, but I have no idea about how to store all the checked value (of the checkboxes) to string and sent it to another activity via intent. Can you guys please help me with this and where should I put the code?

And here is my code :

```
private void fetchFromDatabase() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myDb.open();
    int totalGroup = myDb.countHowManyGroups(Username);
    String groupId[] = myDb.fetchGroupId(Username);
    String groupName[] = myDb.fetchGroupName(Username);
    String flag[] = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalGroup; i++) {

        listCheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
        listCheckBox.setText(groupName[i]);
        listCheckBox.setTag(groupId[i]);

        if (listCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            int x=0;
            flag[x]=listCheckBox.getText().toString();
            x++;
        }


        layout.addView(listCheckBox);
    }
    myDb.close();

    Button bSubmit = new Button(this);
    bSubmit.setText("Submit");
    layout.addView(bSubmit);

    bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (listCheckBox.isChecked()) {

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You have at least two options. First, as you created new CheckBoxes and added them to layout they are now children of layout. So you could iterate through the children of layout. Second, you could add a CheckBox [] checkboxes array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of what you want to store. Do you want to store the id of the selected checkboxes? Then override their `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to save it's `id` on an array (remember that id is 0 unless you set it.)

Do you want to save it's tag? Then override the same method but save the tag instead.

Here is an example of the implementation of `setOnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
List<String> myTagList = new ArrayList<String>();
listCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                myTagList.add(buttonView.getTag());
            else
                myTagList.remove(buttonView.getTag());
        }
    });
```

Comment: And myTagList is a ? String[]?

Comment: It's whatever you want. That's just an example.

Comment: I tried your code, but It still cant store the value, is it another way?

Comment: What do you mean you can't "store" the value? Are you familiar with arrays/collections?

Comment: Not really, I am kinda new to programming, and dont know much about the concept, could you please help a lil bit?

Comment: Like I thought. If you're not familiar with some basic concepts like arrays and lists why are you trying Android? `myTagList` is a `List<String>`

Comment: @Pedro, as OP is `kinda new in android and java programming,` you could be as kind to show the declaration and instantiation of myTagList too.

Comment: `If you're not familiar with some basic concepts like arrays and lists why are you trying Android?`. @Pedro. I definitely do not agree. And as you were as nice to add one code line you also proved that OP is on the right way.

Comment: So you're saying that providing a simple line of code like that one is the best way to learn programming? You think that he will learn something from this other than asking questions on stackoverflow and wait for the correct answer? Without even trying to learn something as basic as lists? OP might be on the right way... but not on the right way of a programmer.

Comment: He is on the right way: 'learning by example'. Time enough to dig into that later. Or even yet today. One does not have to do it your  or my way. Choose your own way.

Comment: Thank you @pedro, I used your code and try to google it, now it worked, thanks